# Cartan integers for Lie superalgebras

Tags: root-systems, lie-superalgebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a basic classical simple Lie superalgebra (BCSLSA in short) with Cartan matrix $A$ of some simple system $\Pi$. Then $A$ satisfies the conditions that

1) $\frac{2a_{ij}}{a_{ii}} \in \mathbb{Z}$ if $a_{ii} > 0$ and

2) $\frac{2a_{ij}}{a_{ii}} \in 2\mathbb{Z}$ if $a_{ii} > 0$ and $i$ is odd.

Note that in the latter case $2 \alpha_i$ is an even root.

My question is when the index $i$ is odd, why the Cartan integer $\frac{2a_{ij}}{a_{ii}}$ has to be an even integer and what is its significance in the Weyl group action (or for the action of odd reflections), Serre relations and in general in the structure of $\mathfrak g$?

Kindly clarify it to me.

Thank you.